# How to read rows from last to first?

Tags: python, csv

I want read rows from last to first. But I can't do this.
I want read in reverse order.

```
stary_patient_2 ='Xs'
nowy_patient_2 = 'VB'
import csv
with open(DATA_DIR+'/stage_2_train_labels_right.csv', 'r') as inp, open(DATA_DIR+'/stage_2_train_labels_right_poprawne.csv', 'w') as out:
    reader = csv.DictReader(inp, delimiter=' ',fieldnames = ['patientId','x', 'y', 'width', 'height', 'Target'])
    writer = csv.DictWriter(out, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in reversed(list(open(DATA_DIR+'/stage_2_train_labels_right.csv'))):
        nowy_patient_2 = row[0]
        print(row)
        print(row[5])
        if not (row[5]=='0' and nowy_patient_2==stary_patient_2):
            writer.writerow({'patientId': row[0], 'x': row[1], 'y': row[2], 'width': row[3], 'height': row[4], 'Target': row[5]})

    stary_patient_2 = nowy_patient_2
```

input file:

```
asdasd 1 2 3 4 5
dddddd 2 2 2 2 2
cccccc 3 2 5 6 1
```

output

```
cccccc 3 2 5 6 1
dddddd 2 2 2 2 2
asdasd 1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for row in reversed(list(open(DATA_DIR+'/stage_2_train_labels_right.csv'))):
```

that is not going to work because you're opening the input file again, and then you're not passing a `csv` object but the file handle.

Just convert `reader` to a `list` to fully read the file, then you can apply `reversed` to the list of rows.

```
with open(os.path.join(DATA_DIR,'stage_2_train_labels_right.csv'), newline="") as inp, open(os.path.join(DATA_DIR,'stage_2_train_labels_right_poprawne.csv'), 'w', newline="") as out:
    reader = csv.DictReader(inp, delimiter=' ',fieldnames = ['patientId','x', 'y', 'width', 'height', 'Target'])
    writer = csv.DictWriter(out, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)
    # read input file fully into a list of rows
    reader = list(reader)
    writer.writeheader()
    # now iterate on reversed list
    for row in reversed(reader):
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is really possible when reading from a file. The file is read via a file pointer that's pointing to the start of the file. As you move the pointer, the byte you're looking at changes as well -- you don't actually have the whole object in memory, and thus you can't reverse it. If you really want this reversed, you're likely going to need to read byte by byte, constantly seeking back one byte, not line by line. 
So, not knowing exactly how the file is going to be formed, here's how a read_last_line might look:

```py
def read_last_line(path):
  buffer = []
  with open(path, 'r') as fh:  # this might be easier not using with
    fh.seek(0, os.SEEK_END) # read last byte
    size = fh.tell()
    r_pos = -1
    while True:
      fh.seek(size + r_pos, 0)
      ch = fh.read(1)
      r_pos -= 1
      if ch == '\n':
        return list(reversed(buffer))
      else:
        buffer.append(ch)
```

There are issues with the above though: Obviously it only gets the last line. You'd need to adapt this to iterate over the file. Second, it reads the file one byte as a time, which may be an issue. Third, it gives back a list, when you may want something else. etc, etc. It's not ideal.

Here are two alternatives:

1. If you have the spare memory, you can just read the whole file in, split it by new lines, then reverse that to get the same effect as you want. But if the files are too big, then that's going to be a problem.
2. If you have control over the file, you can either write it in reverse, or you can do an operation to read in the file and reverse it yourself into a new file. This is weird, so it's less ideal, but it may solve your problem if you can write another version of that file to the disk.

Comment: Any such solution has another issue with CSV in particular: The normal definition of a line doesn't apply to CSV. You need to take into account quoting/escapes, and the defined record separator (e.g. plain `\n` might not be a newline, with only `\r\n` counting).

Comment: Very true, and this would apply to any format whose "lines" are not necessarily separated with a new line character. But, you'd run into the same issue going forwards and backwards. i.e. in either case, you'd need to adapt the code provided here to be useful to your problem area.

Comment: Working forwards is fine, the `csv` module knows how to handle all that. Working backwards, the `csv` module can't help, and you're stuck reimplementing it from scratch, but backwards, making it even more insane.